# Separating mixed values and generating new columns in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

A sample of my data is as follows:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "var Time  
 12O    12
13O 11
22B 45
33Z 22
21L 2
11M 13", header = TRUE)
```

I want to separate values in column "Var" to get the following data:

```
df2 <- read.table(text = " Group1 Group2 Group3 
 1  2   O
1   3   O
2   2   B
3   3   Z
2   1   L
1   1   M", header = TRUE)
```

I tried the following codes:

```
 df2 <- df1 %>% separate(var, into = c('Group1', 'Group2','Group3'), sep = 1)
```

I get an error. I have searched to find the error out, but I have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain the original column, you can use `str_split_fixed` from `stringr` package and `cbind` the result to your existing `dataframe`

```
cbind(df1, str_split_fixed(as.character(df1$var),"", n = 3))

  var Time 1 2 3
1 12O   12 1 2 O
2 13O   11 1 3 O
3 22B   45 2 2 B
4 33Z   22 3 3 Z
5 21L    2 2 1 L
6 11M   13 1 1 M
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned [(Separate outputs empty separator error for each row independently)](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/471), this cannot be done with `tidyr` `separate()`. A possibility is `str_split()` from `stringr` or `strsplit()` from `base R`.

So, using `str_split()`:

```
df1 %>%
 mutate(var = str_split(var, pattern = "")) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 group_by(Time) %>%
 mutate(val = var,
        var = paste0("Group", row_number())) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 ungroup()

   Time Group1 Group2 Group3
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1     2 2      1      L     
2    11 1      3      O     
3    12 1      2      O     
4    13 1      1      M     
5    22 3      3      Z     
6    45 2      2      B
```

Using `strsplit()`:

```
df1 %>%
 mutate(var = strsplit(as.character(var), split = "", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 group_by(Time) %>%
 mutate(val = var,
        var = paste0("Group", row_number())) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 ungroup()
```

To have new columns with appropriate class (character, integer etc.), you can add `convert = TRUE` into `spread()`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible `base/stringr` solution:

```
res<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(stringr::str_replace_all(df1$var
 ,"([0-9])([0-9])([A-Z])","\\1 \\2 \\3"),
          " ")))
 names(res)<-paste0("Group",1:ncol(res))


 cbind(df1["Time"],res)
  Time Group1 Group2 Group3
1   12      1      2      O
2   11      1      3      O
3   45      2      2      B
4   22      3      3      Z
5    2      2      1      L
6   13      1      1      M
```